# мне нужно передать массив с 2 значениями а передается как с 1 помогите пожалуйста, что сделать нужно

Tags: php, массивы, href

Вот ссылка

```
    <a href='size_prod.php?mass[]'>
```

по которой я передаю 2 значения они приходят вот в таком виде:

```
    array(1) { ["Магистр дьявольского культа 2XL"]
```

а мне нужно чтобы данные приходили в таком виде:

```
   array(1) { ["Магистр дьявольского культа,2XL"]
```

как это сделать?

Comment: пентаграмму нарисовать не забыли?

Comment: Не очень понятно каким именно образом вы передаете значения. И абсолютно не понятно где и как именно вы получаете эти данные.